# This TypeScript code throws a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error, but only when there are multiple items

Tags: typescript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I was curious if anyone had ran into this issue. I assume that it might be some kind of recursion happening with the sublistChanged() getting fired, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
export function sublistChanged (ctx: EntryPoints.Client.sublistChangedContext) {
    const rec = X.getTx(ctx)
    const total = _.sumBy(rec.item, (line: POItemSublist | TOItemSublist) => line.quantity * line.custcol_atlas_item_weight!)
    rec.custbody_totalitemweightorder = total
  }
```

Comment: This is probably an artifact of whatever library you are using.  Since you are eventually hitting a custom body field you are not re-triggering the sublist changed event unless by updating the body field an event there tries to update the lines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Typescript with underscore and some other library.

IMO efforts to make Netsuite like more 'traditional' environments are pretty fraught.

Most list comprehensions can be pretty easily managed with just a more Netsuite friendly iterator. I have this as a snippet:

```
function iter(rec:record.Record, listName, cb, doReverse? :boolean){
    
    var i = 0;
    var getV = function (fld){
        return rec.getSublistValue({sublistId:listName, fieldId:fld, line:i});
    };
    if(doReverse){
        i = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:listName}) - 1;
        for(; i>= 0; i--){
            cb(i, getV);
        }
    }else{
        var lim = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:listName});
        for(; i< lim; i++){
            cb(i, getV);
        }
    }
}
```

so your code could look like:

```
export function sublistChanged (ctx: EntryPoints.Client.sublistChangedContext) {
    const rec = ctx.currentRecord;
    let total = 0;
    iter(rec, 'item', (idx, getV)=>{
        total += getV('quantity') * getV('custcol_atlas_item_weight')!;
    });
    rec.setValue({fieldId:'custbody_totalitemweightorder' ,value:total, ignoreFieldChange:true, forceSyncSourcing: true});
  }
```

*ignoreFieldChange* can be skipped if you want normal downstream event handling to fire but you may need this in the case setting the total weight field also normally fires a script.

*forceSyncSourcing* causes the setValue action to finish completely before the next action occurs.