# Somewhere in here is a recursive call, and I cannot seem to find it. I have to use Typescript and Lodash instead of SuiteScript

Tags: typescript, lodash, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Would anybody be able to find the recursion happening in here? And I apologize, I am new to stack overflow, so if my question is not descriptive enough, please let me know.

```
namespace X {
  /**
   * return an instance of the correct record type
   */
  export function getTx(ctx: { currentRecord: record.ClientCurrentRecord }) {
    switch (ctx.currentRecord.type) {
      case record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER:
        return new PurchaseOrder(ctx.currentRecord)
      case record.Type.TRANSFER_ORDER:
        return new TransferOrder(ctx.currentRecord)
      case record.Type.SALES_ORDER:
        return new SalesOrder(ctx.currentRecord)
      default:
        throw new Error('unknown transaction type')
    }
  }

  export function sublistChanged(ctx: EntryPoints.Client.sublistChangedContext) {
    if (ctx.sublistId === 'item') {
      const rec = X.getTx(ctx)
      rec.custbody_totalitemweightorder = _.sumBy(rec.item, (line: POItemSublist | TOItemSublist | SOItemSublist) => line.quantity * line.custcol_atlas_item_weight!)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SO. Would you be able to modify the code you provided into a [mre]? I would also suggest logging on the entry to the methods you think might be part of the recursion, such as `getTx` and `sublistChanged`. Do any of your Order constructors call the above methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This TypeScript code throws a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error, but only when there are multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213651/this-typescript-code-throws-a-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-err)

Comment: Hi Alex, You've asked this same question before.  Why can't you use native Netsuite? If you can show your employer that their chosen library insufficiently captures Netsuite's api then why should you have to use that library?

Comment: @bknights I ended up just using native Netsuite and it fixed the issue. Thank you for the assist. However, we use a tool called NFT (netsuite FastTrack toolkit), and generally it works pretty well. I am new to my company, but I believe my employer wants us to use typescript and lodash instead because it helps protect from errors. For instance, if I do a getValue() suitescript call, then I would have to type in the the field name in quotes and there is no double check on compile time to check if that field actually exists, however with typescript and NFT, the declaration file will double check.

Comment: For Typescript the HITC project is quite useful.